# c# excel interop. Отчет по датам

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Интересует вопрос формирования отчета в Excel. 
Имеется база данных. Но надо выводить в отчет только данные, занесенные в определенный период (в данном случае по неделям). 
Столкнулся с проблемой datetime. Как организовать вывод именно по неделям? 
Т.е. привязка к дате старта и по дату окончания.

Вот пример формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После следует выборка данных. 
Формирование таблиц, их заполнение.

Но как это привязать к временным рамкам?

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Ниже пример выбора года и недели. Вот в этих временных рамках и требуется делать выборку.

```
private void cb_Year_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(cb_Year.Text);
            x3l.FillWeeks(cb_Week, Year);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }


    private void cb_Week_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDate();
    }

    private void SelectedDate()
    {
        try
        {
            Week = Convert.ToInt32(cb_Week.Text);
            dtp_Since.Text = x3l.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(Year, Week).ToShortDateString();
            dtp_Till.Text = x3l.FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(Year, Week).AddDays(+6).ToShortDateString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: А можно код в студию? и точно Iterop хотите использовать? может EpPlus?

Comment: @Dude36 к сожалению, всё написано уже на Interop. Поэтому далее надо продолжать на нем.